# How to pick files in Office folder from the phone using c#.net in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am using liveclientsdk to connect to sdk and I am able to access the files and folders in it.Now I want to upload a file which is saved to phone from mail or some other source to local office space.

IS there any API to choose the files in the Office folder in Windows Phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your app does not have access to these